# Data sources toolbox for VS2012 does not display my entity model

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

After adding an entity model either from the datasources toolbox itself or by adding it => "add" => "new item" it does not show up in the datasources toolbox and therefor i dont get that easy drop and drag functionality.

If I add a dataset it works but that is an older technology (is it not?) everything in my current project are entity models and to change to datasets (which only works if I add `xmlns:yourAlias="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"`) would be .. I don't think best practice and a waste of time.

I have recreated this same process of adding a entity model in VS 2010 and it works 100%, where i have the ability to simply drop and drag from the dataSource toolbox

Maybe ill just wait for VS SP1 before working with it for client projects. :(

**//Edit**

If I add the ADO.net Entity model in VS2010 and then load the project in 2012 it loads fine in the dataSource toolbox. This is an answer but not an ideal work around.

Comment: I am seeing something very similar. When I first add my database connection to the project I can see the objects listed in the Data Sources. If I then navigate away from that window and back again the objects have disappeared from Data Sources windoweven though there is a datasource file within my application's properties. Did you make any headway with fixing this?

Comment: I have not sadly. I am just making it work for now by adding it in VS2010 and then opening it in VS2012. Its the only operation i have had issues with. Once it is added on 2010 everything works as it should.

Comment: Looking at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj613116.aspx it appears VS2010 does it the way that the answer @BukeMan gave so maybe that's why it works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While working on a project I recently faced the same problem. It took me about two days of extensive research but I think I've finally found it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556581

At least for me it solved the problem. Please let me know if it helped you..

Comment: That has worked, but what do you lose by changing the code generation on this way?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I guess you're loosing the features of "Entity Framework 5" (you now can safely uninstall EF5 from your project using NuGet manager).

Comment: so this option is not possible for DbContext?? what a shame :(

Answer (score 1):

Being addicted to L2S, I tried to get familiar with VS2012 and EF5. But I nearly lost my nerves trying to use the data sources toolbox.

Finally I found a solution:

using Object Data Source is now the recommended approach for using EF in databinding scenarios. See this article for more details - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574514. The article also includes a link to revert to the old code generation if that is what you desire.