# Entity Data Model Parent Child relationship in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: entity-framework

I have just upgraded to Visual Studio 2012, I created an entity data model, I was suprised that this was not immediately available in Data Sources, So I added it as an object, is this correct?

Secondly, I did the above and then dragged 2 data grids (which have a parent / child relationship ) onto my WPF window, there is no data in either grid nor a relationship between the 2 grids (tables). The code that is generates is...

```
System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource countPartsEntitiesViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("countPartsEntitiesViewSource")));
            // Load data by setting the CollectionViewSource.Source property:
            // countPartsEntitiesViewSource.Source = [generic data source]
```

Visual Studio 2010 provided data in both tables and the parent child link.

Am I missing something?

Comment: See this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283994/data-sources-toolbox-for-vs2012-does-not-display-my-entity-model